# Manually upgrading Three.js JSON geometry files from r42 to r55

Tags: three.js

I have some JSON files that define geometries, as required by r42 of Three.js's `JSONLoader` class. The files are version 2 of the format.

Is it feasible to manually update these files between versions?

The first obvious difference is that the file is no longer JavaScript, but actual JSON. This was easy to correct for. However the new format has a `metadata` section, and thirty minutes of experimentation with is isn't getting me anywhere.

I'm seeing problems because the `Geometry` object's `material` properties has an empty `materials` array. The resulting geometry has multiple parts with different materials, as seen in r42.

Does anyone know how I might manually tweak these .json files to work with r55?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dragging the file into the [editor](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/editor/), then do `File/Export Geometry`.

Comment: Sounds good, but when I drag the file into the editor the browser loads the content of the file (I see the source as text and the address bar shows a `file://` path). Chrome 24.0.1312.57 on Ubuntu 12.04. I put a breakpoint in the 'drop' handler, but it wasn't hit. Can you create an _Open_ menu item that shows a file chooser dialog? I [created an issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3028) for this.

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to like drag and drop but I was able to open a model in Safari by dragging a file onto it.

Comment: @CrossphireDevelopment, good to know, but I don't think you can run Safari on Linux too easily :) I tried Firefox too, but no luck. I'll try forking the editor repo and adding the feature myself, or just hacking the file in.

Comment: @DrewNoakes - My answer in this item shows a quick fix for drag/drop.

Comment: I've submitted a pull request that fixes drag/drop in Chrome and Firefox: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3035

Comment: @mrdoob, should the import keep per-face material indices and apply them to the loaded objects? If I load the file using JSONLoader (r42), then I see different materials on different faces. However if I import into the editor (r56dev) then the image is solid black. This is true of the included .js files (knight.js, human_walk_0_female.js). Note that the materials I'm referring to are just solid colours and don't need any additional map files.

Comment: @DrewNoakes Sounds like a bug/feature. Do you mind creating another issue?

Comment: [Done, here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3039). I took a look at this one and didn't work out what's going wrong. I don't know enough about the innards of Three.js yet, but it seems that the `materialIndex` is being parsed correctly by the `JSONLoader`, but is then ignored somewhere. If I try to export the geometry, all material information is lost. So unfortunately the editor doesn't help solve this SO question just yet.

Answer (score 2):

I have no complete knowledge how the internals of the format have changed, but here's a couple of hints:

- If you have the source object, the best way would be to re-export/convert. There should now also be more converters and exporters to use if your source format is obscure. If the source is unknown, some Googling might be worth it.
- `metadata` section doesn't matter, it isn't used for anything in the loader.
- There is no more `Geometry.materials`. Instead, JSONLoader's callback returns the loaded materials as a separate parameter to the callback. See [Migration Guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) (r52->r53) for more on that. In fact, the loader interface has changed also in r46.
- `git log` of some example model files (searching for changes there could be your way forward if you really need to manually migrate) suggests that there might be e.g. UV flipping which would be difficult to fix manually but could be worked around in code. But first you'd need to get something to display on screen.

Comment: Thanks Tapio. Unfortunately I don't have the source file. I'll take a look at that migration guide when I revisit this later today. The objects don't have textures mapped, so there aren't any UV's thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix for drag and drop into the editor.  Add this code before the drop event in index.html.  I tested this in Chrome ( 24.0.1312.56 ), Safari and Firefox in OSX.

```
        document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: Looks like we came to the same conclusion. I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/3035) that fixes this issue. In fact, looking at the code, I'm not sure it worked properly in any browser seeing as the Worker callback provided the wrong arguments.

Comment: I was able to import the flamingo model in Safari using the code as it is in revision 55 but the other browsers showed the contents of the model instead of loading it.

Comment: Does the flamingo load with colours applied to faces for you? The .js file I'm loading has per-face material indices, however they seem to be being lost during the import/export process.

Comment: No. I'm not getting colors either.  I was paying more attention to it being able to drag/drop and I didn't notice no colors were showing.

Answer (score 0):

@mrdoob's answer worked after a few patches to the editor ([here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/5852cab635c031a0209e1d0d12f24518c920dfd8) and [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/6d080240ebd2bc0626075fd6a34e66edc6fbbd1e#editor/index.html).)

However it's worth noting that upgrading the files by hand in a text editor is possible, especially if you don't have any UV coords.

- Earlier versions did not use JSON -- they were JavaScript files. The conversion is straightforward.
- You can either ignore the `metadata` section, or else port it from the comments into an object.
- If you do have UV coords, then they must be mapped differently (I believe an axis is flipped)